# Install Ubuntu in different SSD

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I have a HP Omen laptop with 512 GB SSD but I am planning to get a new SSD of 512 GB to insert in other empty slot . I want to keep windows in existing SSD and install Ubuntu in the new one. Please let know if it is possible to do that and if yes, how should I do that. I am new to this and don't know much.

Comment: Yes you can do that.  But you might have to either manually boot off the second SSD through bios options, or you may have to install the bootloader on the first SSD, preferably in the same EFI partition that the windows EFI bootloader is on.

Comment: You need to gpt partition in advance & include ESP. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  And still need Windows fast start up off, drives change to AHCI from RAID or Intel RST (first add AHCI driver to Windows). HP Envy 13 install to external drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413599 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161563/external-hdd-works-on-desktop-but-not-recognized-on-laptop Some laptops will not boot from DVD slot. You may then need /boot on Windows drive. Consider external SSD?

Comment: @user10489 please can you explain in detail as I didnt get  the solution .

Comment: I didn't give a solution.  If I had, I would have put it in an answer.